# An averaged curve/parabola for plotted points in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, curve

I need to get Excel to graph about 5 points into a single curve. I'm looking for is the average of all the point if the points don't line up perfectly. I'm not very familiar with graphing on Excel, so it's very possible I've overlooked some option to get what I'm trying to achieve.

This is an example of what I'm looking for:
[image: Curve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks liek what you're looking to do is add a trendline to a scatterplot.

I've included some screenshots below.

Inital graph showing 3 groups of data we want to 'average':

[image]

Adding trendline to the points:

[image]

Trendline settings:

[image]

Final result:

[image]